# How to load trained fasttext embedding in TorchText?

Tags: fasttext, torchtext

I generated fine-tuned/ trained fasttext embedding based on unsupervised method using the reference here - https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html. Now I am trying to load this embedding into TorchText vocabu.build() function. But I am getting error. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When using Torchtext, there is the vocabulary, and there is the embedding. The vocabulary maps words to indices. For instance, if you have the sentence: "The child ate an apple", it will map it like this `{'the': 0, 'child': 1, 'ate': 2, 'an':3, 'apple': 4}`. It looks like you are using the legacy version of torchtext. If you are starting a brand new project, I would recommend using the newest release. Either way, both ways (the newest and the legacy ways) to properly build a vocabulary are given [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/text/blob/master/examples/legacy_tutorial/migration_tutorial.ipynb).

Loading a pretrained embedding is a separate process. The tutorial you linked to shows how to save the embedding as a .vec or .bin file. You can load that into your model using Gensim. There are some good answers to [this question on Stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20071/how-do-i-load-fasttext-pretrained-model-with-gensim) that can guide you to getting that done. Depending on how you want to use the embedding, you may need to do some processing on it after you load it into your model.

Once you have loaded the embedding, you need to make sure that your vocabulary points to the right indices of the embedding. A simple way to do this is to load the embedding and then iterate through it to build your vocabulary.